# Add custom class to select option on open and close in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to add a custom class to a select option element.

Scenario : When I click and open a select option "class=open" should be added, When it get closed on clicking outside the dom or selecting some option or clicking on the dropdown again should add "class=close".

My code :

```
<select id="sKMob_orderStatus">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<select id="skMob_orderDate">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
$("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").on("mousedown",function(){
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('open');
    console.log("triggered");
});
```

Refer for sample : http://jsfiddle.net/T4yUm/298/

Could anyone suggest an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its working as you want in jsfiddle.

Comment: When it get closed, "class=close" should be added removing "class=open"

Comment: Select closes when outside of DOM... do you want something else?

Comment: I need to add different class on open and close of select option

Comment: @PriyankaS, check my answer. It does what you need.

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay thank you. Can you please see my another question

Comment: @PriyankaS see my answer for both of what you want

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay Please check my updated question

Comment: Select boxes are browser ui elements and we shouldn't attempt to style them beyond basic width / height. Recommend using a select box DOM replacement instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more function to your jquery code like this:

```
 $("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").on("mousedown",function(){
  if($("#sKMob_orderStatus").hasClass('open'))
  {
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
      $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
  }
  else{
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('close');
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('open');
  }

    console.log("triggered");
});
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate")) {
        $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
        $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
                console.log("triggered back");
    }
});

$("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").on("change" ,function(event) {
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
    console.log("triggered back");
});
```

The 2nd function will check if clicked outside the element and it will remove `open` class and add `close` class.

Comment: 1. When we select some option in drop down, the select option will get closed. In this scenario how to add class="close"

Comment: 2. Also If we close the select option by clicking the dropdown again, how to add class="close"

Comment: @PriyankaS, did you checked my updated answer. Its working as per both of your requirements mentioned above.

Comment: @ Himanshu Upadhyay Scenario : 1. Click on the dropdown, dropdown gets opened  - open class is added. 2. Again Click on the dropdown dropdown gets closed - close class is not added

Comment: @PriyankaS do you want before it close add class and then close dropdwon???

Comment: @ Himanshu Upadhyay No. In the above code only on option select and clicking on outisde dom "Close class is added"....But When select is in opened state if we click on downdrop again, it gets closed -  in this scenario close class is not getting add.

Comment: Hi @PriyankaS, I updated my code again. So now when you click on the select (only select, not the 1st option a) again, it will get the close class.

Comment: Hi when we right click on the dropdown, it is not opening dropdown, but it adding class as open

Comment: You keep adding different scenarios @PriyankaS. The answer gives perfect solution as per your OP.

Comment: oh, never mind @PriyankaS. I think you can do it now. You have got 16 reputation now.

Comment: i did it. Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 1):

use `focusout`

```
 $("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").focusout(function(){
     $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
     $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
    });
```

**OR click on document(means dropdown closes)**

```
 $(document).on('click',function(){
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
});
```

**When Select some option**

```
$("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").change(function() {
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
        $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
});
```

**While select opens:**

```
$("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").focus(function () {
        $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
        $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
}
```

**For you comment when click on arrow**

```js
$("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").on("mousedown",function(){
 $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('open');
  $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('close');
 console.log("triggered");
});
 $("#sKMob_orderStatus").focusout(function(){
     $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
     $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
    });
    var flag=false;
     $("#sKMob_orderStatus").on('click',function(){
     if(flag){
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').removeClass('open');
    $('#sKMob_orderStatus').addClass('close');
    flag=false;
    }
    else
     flag=true;
});
```

```css
.close{
  color:red;
}
.open{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sKMob_orderStatus">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @PriyankaS you have to use 2 functions(one for `focusout` and one when select something(`change`)

Comment: @PriyankaS  you can choose one of function `focusout `or on `click` on document

Comment: How to added close class - If select is already in open state, if we click dropdown it get closed

Comment: you want when select is opening add class close??/

Comment: I mean when select on focus??

Comment: No. Steps to test :
1. Click on the dropdown arrow, dropdown gets opened - open class is added. 
2. Again Click on the dropdown arrow, dropdown gets closed - close class is not added

Comment: I suggest you to make function for each select(no both of them in same function)

Comment: Yes . Thank you

Comment: I realy appricate if you mark as answer if you use my code

Answer (score 1):

try this tricky alternative way

```js
$(function(){    
    $("#sKMob_orderStatus, #skMob_orderDate").on("focus focusout change",function(e){        
        switch(e.type){            
            case 'focus' :
                $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('close');
                break;
            case 'focusout' :
            case 'change' :
                $(this).addClass('close').removeClass('open');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.open{color:green;}
.close{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sKMob_orderStatus">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<select id="skMob_orderDate">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```